# OWL-?? to OWL-RL for GraphDB (OWLIM)

Tags: owl, ontology, inference, owlim, graphdb

I am trying to use GraphDB-SE triplestore to store Einstein Riddle and use ruleset to infer the answers. GraphDB has build in support for OWL2-RL and OWL2-QL.
According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL)

> OWL 2 RL supports all axioms of OWL 2 apart from disjoint unions of
>   classes (DisjointUnion) and reflexive object property axioms
>   (ReflexiveObjectProperty).

**Q1:** Why GraphDB is not able to infer it ?

**Q2:** If I'm using something out of OWL-RL, how can I transform my ontology (OWL file) to OWL-RL ? (I cannot find more information, about this profile. Practical information like "Use this, don't use this.")"

**Q3:** If GraphDB doesnt full-support OWL2-RL, what part is not supported? How can I transform my model to be able to infer expected results using GraphDB?

My model of owl is from [this web](http://web.archive.org/web/20120121042217/http://db.iis.nsk.su/persons/ponom/ontologies/) and also [altered model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9n4qtbwv9wo0d0/zebra.owl?dl=0) using exactly 1 QCR instead of functional and inverse functional properties with someValuesfrom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better quote from the standard would be

> Restricting the way in which constructs are used makes it possible to implement reasoning systems using rule-based reasoning engines [...] [I]n SubClassOf axioms, the constructs in the subclass and superclass expressions must follow the usage patterns shown in Table 2.

And the Table 2 prohibit, e.g., the use of `OneOf` construction on the right-hand size of the `SubClassOf` axiom. And this construction is crucial for the Einstein Riddle problem.

Answering **Q2**: if you look at the Table 2 quoted above, you will find that OWL 2 RL is really very restrictive profile. In particular, it prohibits an existential restriction on the right-hand side of subsumption. This means that it is usually impossible to transform arbitrary OWL 2 DL ontology into an RL one.